# OpenGL SSBO length determination

Tags: opengl-es

I would like to know when the length of a SSBO is determined and if we can grow a SSBO size in a compute shader(OpenGL ES 3.1) as we can write on a SSBO in a shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffer objects are allocated on the CPU at a known size. It's not possible to grow them in the shader.